# sum the contents of a delimted column in an oracle table column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have a column in an oracle database table which has amounts comma separated. I have a requirement to sum the comma separated numerics and display.

Stored procedure could be an option. After much googling I have found the below solution as well for columns say, COL1, COL2, COL3, AMOUNT. Here AMOUNT is comma separated as below,

```
123423,23523,5454,242342
```

Solution found after much search,

```
select 
  a.COL1 as COL1,
  a.COL2 as COL2,
  a.COL2 as COL3,
  sum(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.AMOUNT, '\d+', 1, occ)) as SUM
from 
  TBL1 a,
  (select level occ from DUAL connect by level < 3000) 
 group by a.COL1, a.COL2, a.COL3;
```

But the problem here is this is a huge table and because of the group by, it is taking a long time. Since we are summing up the data in an individual column value of a single row and not aggregating with other rows, is there a performing way of doing the same?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Is your question actually *is there a performing way of doing the same?* cos if it is.. see jarlh's comment :)

Comment: i cant modify the table or the way data is stored.. thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

The bad design of this table has already caused you problems, but this solution might work:

```
SELECT 
  a.COL1 as COL1,
  a.COL2 as COL2,
  a.COL2 as COL3,
  (
      SELECT SUM(trim(regexp_substr(amount, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)))
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY regexp_substr(amount , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ) as AMOUNT
FROM tbl1 a;
```